# Protege Reasoner popups errors after writing dataTypeProperties using Jena

Tags: rdf, jena, owl, ontology, protege

I created ontology in protege. I have some dataTypeProperties of which ranges are set as integer, dateTime and string.

In my java application i am using Jena api to write onto owl files, i am handling dataTypeProperties with this single method.:

```
public void setDataTypeProperty(String resourceURI, String propertyName, String propertyValue) 
{
    if (resourceURI==null)
    return;

    Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

    //read model from file
    InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(inputFileName);

     if (in == null) 
     {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException( "File: " + inputFileName + " not found");
     }       
     model.read(in, "");
     try {
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


     // Add property to Model
     Resource resource = model.createResource(resourceURI);
     resource.addProperty(model.createProperty(baseURI+propertyName), model.createLiteral(propertyValue));


     //Writing model to file
        try {
            FileWriter out = new FileWriter( inputFileName );
            model.write( out, "RDF/XML-ABBREV" );
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
}
```

After writing to owl file, it looks like this:

```
....
<File rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/administrator/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-5#677f5c75-7527-45e2-8430-829466027034"> 
    <filePeakLocation>ismaila swabi</filePeakLocation> //String Datatype
    <filePeakDay>6</filePeakDay> //Integer Datatype 
    <fileLastAccessed>2014-07-26T13:17:49</fileLastAccessed> //dateTime
    <created>2014-07-26T13:17:27</created> //dateTime
    <hasPath>/examples/run.sh</hasPath>  //String Datatype
    <fileAccessedLocation>ismaila swabi_atTime_2014-07-26T13:17:49</fileAccessedLocation>
    <filePeakHour>13</filePeakHour> //Integer
</File>
....
```

The problem is that now if I open my owl file in protege and run reasoner (Fact++), it popups errors as below:

[image]

All the errors shown by reasoner are of properties having ranges of integer or dataTime datatypes. Properties with ranges gives no error.

Can someone points out the reason of the errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty sure that the problem is that you are using this single function `public void setDataTypeProperty()`  for writing strings, integers, and dateTime. Your function writes all values as plain literal. you should check [TypedLiterals](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/notes/typed-literals.html)

In jena try  `model.createTypedLiteral(arg0)`

Comment: I made use of `model.createTypedLiteral()` But now the problem is that the date is written in java format, not in `XMLSchema#dateTime` format. 
Now it looks like this:
 
  `<File rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/administrator/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-5#5d1b7615-b5c7-45d5-aaa4-2d80915fe130">
    <created rdf:datatype="java:java.util.Date">Sat Jul 26 16:03:42 PKT 2014</created>
    <hasPath rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    >/Untitled Document</hasPath>
  </File>`

Comment: Wrong datatype. It's not java:java.util.Date, it's http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime.  Also, Sat Jul 26 16:03:42 PKT 2014 is not a legal XSD datetime.  Either try using a Calendar (not a java date) or, bertter, take control and name the datatype you want with a different createTypedLiteral call.

Comment: @AndyS  I tried calendar but it also writes wrongly `<created rdf:datatype="java:java.util.Date">Sat Jul 26 17:37:27 PKT 2014</created>`   please someone guide o how to store xml date via `model.createTypedLiteral(date)`

Comment: If you got datatype `java:java.util.Date`, it doesn't sound like you actually used Calendar.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor , My program passes date as `Date propertyValue`, So I did the job as   `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.setTime(propertyValue);
  
  Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();` ... `resource.addProperty(model.createProperty(baseURI+propertyName), model.createTypedLiteral(cal.getTime()));`  and still it saves as `java:java.util.Date`

Comment: @SyedRahmanMashwani Calendar#getTime() returns a date, so you're still passing a Date, not a Calendar.  What do you get if you do `resource.addProperty(…,model.createTypedLiteral(cal))`, like Andy suggested?